# React - firebase hosting not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I`m creating api using react and firebase.

But there is no hosting. And the Chrome browser requires a cache emptying and a strong refresh to get a 404 page.

url is https://jp-db-2018.firebaseapp.com/api/getChannels

in conclusion I want to use react and firebase for hosting.

Here are the project settings.

Thank you for your advice.

firebase.json

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
         "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/**",
        "function": "api"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [ {
      "source" : "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
      "headers" : [ {
        "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "value" : "*"
      } ]
      }, {
     "source" : "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
      "headers" : [ {
        "key" : "Cache-Control",
        "value" : "max-age=7200"
      } ]
      }, {
      "source" : "404.html",
      "headers" : [ {
        "key" : "Cache-Control",
        "value" : "max-age=300"
      } ]
    } ],
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "trailingSlash": false
  }
}
```

/src/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const config = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxxxxx",
  databaseURL: "xxxxxxxx",
  projectId: "xxxxxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxx"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

/functions/index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccountKey.json');
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://jp-db-2018.firebaseio.com"
});
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const db = admin.firestore();

app.get('/getChannels', (req, res) => {
  res.json({code: 200});
});
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

tree view

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Seems to be working fine. You specified that you want it to say `code:200` in a json response in your firebase function. Were you expecting something else?

Comment: I do not know why, but it's work. But the source in the question is redeployed, so it is not working. I do not know why.

Comment: I don't understand. Hosting can take a little while sometimes. Also, you might need to flush your browser cache if you are not seeing what I see.

Comment: Thank you for answer. The cache seems to be correct.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying it is not working? Have you fixed it? I am unclear what the question is now.

Comment: When I created the project, I got yes in the rewrites option and it was fixed.